# Unexpected match in .Net for a regex on path that works in JavaScript

Tags: c#, .net, regex, regex-negation, regex-group

> CLARIFICATION: I am not asking for a pattern. I am asking why a
>   pattern works in PHP and JavaScript but not in .Net.

I am trying to get the bottom level folder from a path. The pattern works in PHP and JavaScript but returns an unexpected result in .Net. I would like to understand why .Net returns what it returns with this pattern.

Given this path:

> "c:\level0\level1\level2\filename.ext"

I am trying to match

> "level2"

This is the pattern I am using: (editor keeps taking out the slashes, so here is a picture:

[image: Regex pattern]

What I expect to match :

> level2

What C# matches:

> c:\level0\level1

For completeness, here is the pattern in the RegEx instance:
[image: VS pattern]

How does this pattern need to be specified for .Net to match the bottom level folder?

Comment: Something like `Regex.Match(path, @".*\\([^\\]+)\\.*").Groups[1].Value`. Or with named group `Regex.Match(path, @".*\\(?<name>[^\\]+)\\.*").Groups["name"].Value`

Comment: Instead of editing the post and attacking the user in the edit message, you _could_ leave a comment and ping them to ask for clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you [have the right security permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.fileinfo.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2) on the filesystem you run the code on you don't need to use Regex for this, the framework already contains what you need by way of `FileInfo`:

```
new FileInfo(@"c:\level0\level1\level2\filename.ext").Directory.Name
```

If you dont have access to the file system you can also use `Path.GetDirectoryName()` which is a bit more straightforward than Regex I think:

```
string directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"c:\level0\level1\level2\filename.ext");

//outputs "c:\level0\level1\level2"

string folder = directoryPath.Split(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar).Last();
```

Fiddle for the latter of the two answers [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3KeoYU)

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, I will .use it. The question, however, is about RegEx and I would like to understand why this pattern doesn't work in .Net.

Answer (score 1):

You could also just use Split and linq:

```
string path = @"c:\level0\level1\level2\filename.ext";
string result = path.Split('\\').Reverse().Skip(1).First();
//outputs: level2
```